# C# : How to get anonymous type from LINQ result

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get NewsImage field and list of categories Ids that associated with the news in Many to Many relationship ... but it gives me error:

The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

My code looks like this

```
  var Result1 = (from c in db.News
                   join d in db.Categories
                on c.NewsId equals d.News.Select(l => l.NewsId)
                   where c.NewsId == 1
                   select new { c.NewsImagePath, d.CategoryId }).ToList();
```

Comment: make sure  `c.NewsId` and `dn.News.Select` have same type.  `Select` returns `IEnumberable` .

Comment: post your models here to have better understanding. If you have `naviagation properties ` defined then It should be simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a navigation property defining the n-n relation I would write:

```
var result = db.News
  .Where(x => x.NewsId == 1)
  .SelectMany(x => x.Categories, 
              (news, category) => new { news.NewsImagePath, category.CategoryId })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Absolutely! `join` on navigation property `select` with `FirstOrDefaut()` is ridiculous.

Comment: @LeBaptiste, Thank you so much :) , this EXACTLY what i was looking for. If you don't mind, i would be thankful if you could   show me how can i achieve the same thing using LINQ query instead of Lambda expression

Comment: @Lucy To get the equivalent query syntax, replace `join d in db.Categories on ...` in your query with `from d in c.Categories`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is inside the `on` statement.

```
on c.NewsId equals d.News.Select( l => l.NewsId )
```

The Select on the right-hand side will return a `IEnumerable` of news, which is not what you want.

Something like this would technically work:

```
on c.NewsId equals d.News.Select( l => l.NewsId ).FirstOrDefault()
```

But it does not make sense logically.

I suspect the whole query should be built differently. I think you want to join when the category list of news contains the news item. In that case, you can't use the `join` statement, it would look somewhat like this:

```
from n in db.News
from c in db.Categories
where c.News.Select( ne => ne.NewsId ).Contains( n.NewsId )
select new { n.NewsImagePath, c.CategoryId }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

the LeBaptiste's answer works well, i would be thankful if you could show me how can i achieve LeBaptiste's answer using using LINQ query instead of Lambda expression

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible, `SelectMany` is not implemented in the query syntax, you have to use the method syntax in case you want to use it...